# Does azure "az webapp up" run build processes?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

Currently I'm writing a Django (python) application running on Microsoft Azure cloud. Azure offers several different ways to deploy your app:

1. Zip upload
2. Git repository
3. Cloud shell using "[az webapp up](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/webapp/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-webapp-az-webapp-up)" command

In the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-configure-python), it's mentioned that build processes are or can be configured to run automatically during the deployment (in this case, running pip install -r requirements.txt). However, no mention of this is made regarding the third option.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is listed as an "experimental command" your best bet for documentation is the man page.

```
$>az webapp up --help

Command
    az webapp up : (Preview) Create and deploy existing local code to the web app, by running the
    command from the folder where the code is present. Supports running the command in preview mode
    using --dryrun parameter. Current supports includes Node, Python,.NET Core, ASP.NET, staticHtml.
    Node, Python apps are created as Linux apps. .Net Core, ASP.NET and static HTML apps are created
    as Windows apps. If command is run from an empty folder, an empty windows web app is created.

Arguments
    --dryrun       : Show summary of the create and deploy operation instead of executing it.
    --location -l  : Location. Values from: `az account list-locations`. You can configure the
                     default location using `az configure --defaults location=<location>`.
    --sku          : The pricing tiers, e.g., F1(Free), D1(Shared), B1(Basic Small), B2(Basic
                     Medium), B3(Basic Large), S1(Standard Small), P1(Premium Small), P1V2(Premium
                     V2 Small), PC2 (Premium Container Small), PC3 (Premium Container Medium), PC4
                     (Premium Container Large).  Allowed values: B1, B2, B3, D1, F1, FREE, P1, P1V2,
                     P2, P2V2, P3, P3V2, PC2, PC3, PC4, S1, S2, S3, SHARED.

Resource Id Arguments
    --ids          : One or more resource IDs (space-delimited). If provided, no other 'Resource Id'
                     arguments should be specified.
    --name -n      : Name of the web app. You can configure the default using 'az configure
                     --defaults web=<name>'.
    --subscription : Name or ID of subscription. You can configure the default subscription using
                     `az account set -s NAME_OR_ID`.

Global Arguments
    --debug        : Increase logging verbosity to show all debug logs.
    --help -h      : Show this help message and exit.
    --output -o    : Output format.  Allowed values: json, jsonc, none, table, tsv, yaml.  Default:
                     json.
    --query        : JMESPath query string. See http://jmespath.org/ for more information and
                     examples.
    --verbose      : Increase logging verbosity. Use --debug for full debug logs.

Examples
    View the details of the app that will be created, without actually running the operation
        az webapp up -n MyUniqueAppName --dryrun


    Create a web app with the default configuration, by running the command from the folder where
    the code to deployed exists.
        az webapp up -n MyUniqueAppName


    Create a web app in a sepcific region, by running the command from the folder where the code to
    deployed exists.
        az webapp up -n MyUniqueAppName -l locationName


    Deploy new code to an app that was originally created using the same command
        az webapp up -n MyUniqueAppName -l locationName
```

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR  run this before deploying  **`az webapp config appsettings set -g MyResourceGroup -n MyUniqueAppName --settings SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`**

```
PS C:\> az webapp config appsettings set --h

Command
    az webapp config appsettings set : Set a web app's settings.

Arguments
    --settings          : Space-separated appsettings in a format of <name>=<value>.
    --slot -s           : The name of the slot. Default to the productions slot if not specified.
    --slot-settings     : Space-separated slot appsettings in a format of <name>=<value>.

Resource Id Arguments
    --ids               : One or more resource IDs (space-delimited). If provided, no other
                          'Resource Id' arguments should be specified.
    --name -n           : Name of the webapp. You can configure the default using 'az configure
                          --defaults web=<name>'.
    --resource-group -g : Name of resource group. You can configure the default group using `az
                          configure --defaults group=<name>`.  Default: AvidX-Dv-BIOps-RG.
    --subscription      : Name or ID of subscription. You can configure the default subscription
                          using `az account set -s NAME_OR_ID`.

Global Arguments
    --debug             : Increase logging verbosity to show all debug logs.
    --help -h           : Show this help message and exit.
    --output -o         : Output format.  Allowed values: json, jsonc, none, table, tsv, yaml.
                          Default: json.
    --query             : JMESPath query string. See http://jmespath.org/ for more information and
                          examples.
    --verbose           : Increase logging verbosity. Use --debug for full debug logs.
```